# Kotlin Spring Boot app and GCP service_account configuration: What is the best practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I am creating a Kotlin Spring Boot app, which needs to access an API that is hosted in GCP, and to access that API, I need to authenticate my client with the `service_account` `key.json` file.

**I am not sure how to configure the `key.json` file properly and what is the best practice.** ?

To help to understand more, I'll have the app finally run a Docker container.

Comment: Where will live your container? On Google Cloud? Elsewhere?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere My app will lives outside of GCP. The rest server I want to access is in GCP.

Comment: WHere will it live exactly? On prem? on other cloud?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it will be on prem.

Answer (score 0):

A container is not a safe place. It's not encrypted and it's easy to read file in it. It's a simple file packaging format in the end.

When you run your container, the best practice is to mount a volume alongside the container with the secret loaded in it.

To store the service account JSON file (the secret), follow your own best practices in term of secret management: keep the file in a secure location, restrict the access, cipher it if you can,...